# AttributeType::Handle Validation and Unique

Tags: validation, records, attributetype

I'm building a plugin that has a column in the DB which is `unique` and essentially an `AttributeType::Handle`.

Here is the piece from the record:

```
return array(
    'key' => array(AttributeType::Handle, 'default' => '', 'required' => true),
);
```

And in my service after the `$model` has passed validation:

```
if ($record->save()) {
    // update id on model (for new records)
    $model->setAttribute('id', $record->getAttribute('id'));
    return true;
} else {
    $model->addErrors($record->getErrors());
    return false;
}
```

When does that handle validation happen? If I pass something that wouldn't pass handle validation (spaces or a reserved word), it doesn't save the record in the database, but it doesn't throw any errors.

In addition, is there a way to throw an error when the value isn't unique? Again, the record doesn't save if I use a key that is already in the DB, but there is no error.

Happy to provide more code if necessary, just didn't want to overcomplicate the question. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, just realized how dumb I was. I just needed to add the AttributeType::Handle to the model as well. But, I still have the question about throwing an error on uniqueness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In addition, is there a way to throw an error when the value isn't unique? Again, the record doesn't save if I use a key that is already in the DB, but there is no error.

If you use `'unique' => true` in an attribute on your record, Craft will use Yii's [CUniqueValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUniqueValidator) class to verify the uniqueness of an attribute in the database.

`$record->validate()` will fail and you can use `$record->getErrors()` to get the error message.

```
return array(
    'key' => array(AttributeType::Handle, 'default' => '', 'required' => true, 'unique' => true),
);
```

Comment: Ah, got it. `$record->save()` was always returning false, but I wasn't getting the errors from the record validation correctly. Got it working now, thanks!